# I want to connect to SFTP serving for testing purpose currently i am using UFT as automation tool

Tags: windows

As I am new to UFT so I want to connect to SFTP server and uploading my file from my local to SFTP and download the same file from SFTP so please suggest me how can I connect to SFTP using UFT.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

UFT Uses VBScripting and DotNetFactory for programming, So you can search for how to transfer files using VBS or .net.

You probably will have to download some components.

Below is one such resource

https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/sftp.asp

Comment: Hi Sumeet Singh,
Thank you for your valuable information.